# How to control a photo gallery mc from within another movieclip as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I found AS for my photo galley and its working fine on the main frameline. Problem is that I want to put it inside of the other mc (sliding out menu) and there it stops working.

Sliding menu is: menu_mc and inside of that should be my gallery.
And like I said script working fine on the main scene.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
var numOfPix:Number = 6;
var pos:Array = [0, 190, 380, 570, 860, 1050];
var theInfo:Array = ["The First Car", "The Second Car", "The Third Car", "The Fourth Car", "The Fifth Car", "The Sixth Car"];
var w:Number = _level0.the1_btn._width;
var h:Number = _level0.the1_btn._height;
//~~~ The text Format ~~~
var theFmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
theFmt.align = "center";
theFmt.color = 0xFF6600;
theFmt.font = "theFont";
theFmt.size = 20;
theFmt.bold = true;
//
for (i=1; i<=numOfPix; i++) {
    _level0["the"+i+"_btn"].createTextField("theNum_txt", 1, 0, 0, w, h);
    _level0["the"+i+"_btn"].theNum_txt.text = i;
    _level0["the"+i+"_btn"].theNum_txt.setTextFormat(theFmt);
}
//
_level0.info_txt.selectable = false;
_level0.info_txt.setNewTextFormat(theFmt);
//
for (i=1; i<=pos.length; i++) {
    _level0["the"+i+"_btn"].n = i;
    _level0.info_txt.text = _level0.theInfo[0];
    _level0["the"+i+"_btn"].onRelease = function() {
        _level0.thePix_mc.panorama_mc._x = _level0.pos[this.n-1]*-1;
        _level0.info_txt.text = _level0.theInfo[this.n-1];
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you get any errors?

Comment: no, nothing, i think I miss some line in the beginning but because im new in flash i dont know commands